# Software for storing and easy visualization of multidimensional data slices

Tags: gratis, data-visualization, charts

I have several hundreds of values, each corresponding a tuple of features from different dimensions. For example, the value is *price*, dimensions are:

- Fruit: apples, oranges, bananas (enum dimension)
- Origin: US, Argentina, Marocco, ...
- Month: Feb 2014, Jan 2014, Dec 2013, ...
- Minimum buying volume: 1 kg, 10 kg, 1000 kg (pseudo-measure)

I'm looking for a cross-platform software for storing such data and *easy* visualization of data slices: drawing different charts (3D, stacked, area, percentage, bar), selecting several features for axes.

Examples:

- Line chart with prices of apples for 1 kg from Argentina (month by X axis).
- Bar chart with prices of oranges, origin by X axis, and grouped by minimum buying volume.
- 3D chart with prices of bananas, month by X axis, minimum being volume by Y axis, prices averaged by origin.

Comment: Time would be nice too, with a this month/last month compression, or April for every year of data

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/) for this.
It is not exactly easy, but not too hard either once you get the concept.

You have many options to insert your data (for instance CSV).
Then you can generate drill into the dimensions you want and generate nice graphs.

You can also define automatically-updated dashboards and reports.

The community edition (CE) is open source (Apache 2 license) and can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/).
I used it on Linux and Windows, but it also works on Mac OS X.

[image]

Comment: The free community edition is not easy to find on the web site - you need to look in http://community.pentaho.com/ to find it.  Also I don't think that the "participation agreement" would meet the requirements of ANY open source licence.

Comment: Wikipedia states that the Community Edition is under Apache 2 License, which means open source. I haven't seen any "participation agreement" when downloading from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend taking a look at [python](http://python.org) + either if your data is really big [pyTables](http://www.pytables.org/moin) & [MatPlotLib](http://matplotlib.org/) or for moderate sizes of data [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) - either way you get a free, cross platform, totally customisable view of your data.

Comment: There are only hundreds, maximum serveral thousands of values. Pandas looks interesting. I don't need to analyze the data (means, distributions, etc.), only visualize. I have a little experience with Matplotlib and that's the thing I'd like to avoid. Matplotlib is powerful, but not simple.

Comment: Take a look at the examples at: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/rplot.html

Comment: This all sounds nice and I personally use them for everything, but it basically requires him to write his own software. While the OP might be able to do that, it won't help someone who for example wants to ditch Excel